Understanding concurrency and data Consistency in concurrent Merge Into operations in BigQuery
I'm working on a project where I'm using BigQuery for data manipulation, using the MERGE statement to INSERT or UPDATE rows based on a key. However, I've encountered some issues with duplicates due to concurrent MERGE operations (the table is partitioned).
Looking into the documentation:

The UPDATE, DELETE, and MERGE DML statements are called mutating DML statements. If you submit one or more mutating DML statements on a table while other mutating DML jobs on it are still running (or pending), BigQuery runs up to 2 of them concurrently, after which up to 20 are queued as PENDING.

Seems to be related to the concurrency of requests, not sure how this handle internaly.
Anyone experienced this behavior recently of happening race conditions for concurrent executions?
Thanks in advance

Hi @ddss, It appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so if you have a support plan please create a new GCP support case. Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the issue tracker describing your issue.
